# Regression problem -- which methods are appropriate?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

Given:

- A non-differentiable, non-smooth function $f(p,q) \rightarrow R$
- A set of points $S=\{(x_0,y_0), \ldots, (x_n,y_n)\}$
- Bounds as $p_{min} < p < p_{max}$, and $q_{min} < q < q_{max}$

I want to efficiently compute any $(p_{opt},q_{opt})$ values as parameters of $f$ which minimise an error function like least-squares between $f$ and $S$.

Which methods are best suited to this problem? Is a [non-linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) technique the best way to go?

I would also like to implement a solution with Python, if anyone can suggest any packages which I could use.

Comment: One possibility to consider is scipy's implementation of the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm. I have used this quite a bit with good success.

Comment: Wow, [Differential Evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) looks very interesting, thanks!